# MGCV: Signal Regression with 2-D Predictors

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Does anyone have any insights on how to perform signal regression when the smooth predictor has more than one dimension? The single dimension setting,

```
b <- gam(y ~ s(X,by=L,k=20),
```

is covered in depth in mgcv documentation (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/linear.functional.terms.html). I am having trouble identifying what the equivalent would look like for a two-dimensional predictor using a tensor basis, e.g.

```
b <- gam(y ~ te(X, Y, by = L, k = c(20, 20)).
```

More specifically, what would the dimensions of X and Y be? Would L contain the vectorized two-dimensional predictors in the spirit of the one-dimensional example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to work out the smooth using SmoothCon() which was giving me errors. The solution is simply to vectorize and extend the model matrices used for a one-dimensional signal regression described in the original question above. Say you have outcomes $z_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ and your functional predictor is $f(x_i, y_i)$ where $x_i = \{x_{ij}\}_{j = 1, \ldots, J}$ and $y_i = \{y_{ik}\}_{k = 1, \ldots, K}$. Let $X = [1_K \otimes x_1, \ldots, 1_K \otimes x_n]$, $Y = [y_1  \otimes 1_J, \ldots, y_n  \otimes 1_J]$, and $L = [\text{vec}\{f(x_1, y_1)\}, \ldots, \text{vec}\{f(x_n, y_n)\}]$, then the appropriate signal regression model for a two-dimensional functional predictor can be fit using the command,

```
b <- gam(z ~ te(X, Y, by = L, k = c(20, 20))).
```